# CouchDB: query reduced value on complex key with timeframe

Tags: nosql, couchdb

Application user can perform different tasks. Each kind of task has unique identifier. Each user activity is recorded to database.

So we have following Event entity to keep in database:

```
{
    "user_id": 1,
    "task_id": 2,
    "event_dt": [
        2013, 11, 15, 10, 0, 0, 0
    ]
}
```

I need to know how many tasks of each type were performed by particular user during particular timeframe. Timeframe might be quite long (i.e. rolling chart for last year is requested).

For better understanding, map function might be something like:

```
emit([doc.user_id, doc.task_id, doc.event_dt], 1)
```

and it might be queried using `group_level=2` (or `group_level=1` in case just number of user events is needed).

Is it possible to answer above question by making single view query using map/reduce mechanism? Do I have to use list functionality (though it may cause performance issues)?

Comment: you can't, the first key need to be a time/date in order to support range query.

Comment: Yeah, I know. But timestamp as first field makes group/reduce useless as (almost) each record will have unique key. That's why I created a question. Perhaps, I don't think in CouchDB way enough.

Answer (score -1):

Just use flat key `[doc.user_id, doc.task_id].concat(doc.event_dt)` since it will simplify request and grouping logic:

- with `group_level=1`: you'll get amount of tasks per user for all time
- with `group_level=2`: amount of specific task ids per user for all time
- with `group_level=3`: same as above but in context of specific year
- with `group_level=4`: same as above but also grouped by months
  etc. by days, hours, minutes and seconds

For instance, the result for `group_level=3` may be:

```
{"rows":[
    {"key": ["user1", "task1", 2012], "value": 3},
    {"key": ["user1", "task2", 2013], "value": 14},
    {"key": ["user1", "task3", 2013], "value": 15},
    {"key": ["user2", "task1", 2012], "value": 9},
    {"key": ["user2", "task4", 2012], "value": 26},
    {"key": ["user2", "task4", 2013], "value": 53},
    {"key": ["user3", "task1", 2013], "value": 5}
]}
```

Comment: Let's imagine I'm interested in user2 activities for 2013. In this case I don't need timerange, ok.
But anyway, how would my view query look like?
`key=["user2", ???, 2013]&group_level=3`

Comment: That's would be a different view's key. You need all the cases? Seems like I miss whole your question idea.

Comment: To answer on your question, you may have multiple emits with different keys within single view or have different views for each query case. Or just setup thirdparty search tools like ElasticSearch or couchdb-lucene which handles dynamic queries quite well.

Comment: Sorry, I should have describe my findings in more details. Yes, multiple views could be used there. For example, `emit([doc.user_id, doc.event_dt], doc.event_id])` (to gather all user events for a timerange) and `emit([doc.user_id, doc.event_id, doc.event_dt], 1)` with `sum(values)` reduce function (to make needed calculations). Though, this needs too much backend code work (pagination and handling each event type one by one). Needless to say, this leads to multiple rq/rs to database and affects performance badly. I thought there might an elegant native CouchDB way to sort this out.